# The mdfind command on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, geektool

When I try to find the all .txt files on my Mac using the mdfind command, it just returns only one .txt file back. So why ? And how to find all the .txt files on my Mac with "mdfind"?

```
somebody@MacAir:~ somebody$ mdfind -name *.txt
/Users/somebody/20160408_2.txtenter
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want this:

```
mdfind -name .txt
```

You see, `mdfind` automatically assumes wildcards, so you don't need to try to pass it a wildcard.

And it turns out that since you didn't shell-escape your `*`, you weren't actually passing that wildcard to `mdfind` like you intended. Instead, you were giving it to the shell, and the shell was "globbing", or replacing it with the list of files in your current working directory (`/Users/somebody/`) that matched the pattern `*.txt`. So how the shell was really calling `mdfind` was probably something more like this:

```
mdfind -name 20160408_2.txt SomeOtherFile.txt YetAnotherFile.txt AndSoOn.txt
```

Comment: Testing this because of another Q in Ask Different… `-name "Micro"` returns all the Microsoft apps, but `-name "soft"` doesn't. It seems to be assuming "begins with" rather than "contains"